# how to detect merged cells in vba (Word 2010)

Tags: vba, ms-word

I would like to detect and skip merged cells in vba on word 2010.

I'm making a macro which need to write in the first column but I've some merged cells and I don't want to write in. 
All examples I found was for Excel.

I tried to detect the number of columns per rows but that didn't works. I got `"Error 5991 table has vertically merged cells"`.

So how can I just skip the row when I get merged cells ?

```
Sub test()

Dim Ro As Integer, Col As Integer


        'init 
        Count = 1
        Col = 1
        For Ro = 4 To ActiveDocument.Tables(4).Rows.Count
           'format 
            If Count < 10 Then
                flag = "0"
            Else
                flag = ""
            End If

            'detect merge
            If ActiveDocument.Tables(4).Rows(Ro).Cells.Count = 9 Then

                ActiveDocument.Tables(4).Cell(Ro, Col).Range.Text = "R" & flag & CStr(Count)
                Count = Count + 1

            Else

                Ro = Ro + 1
            End If



        Next Ro
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

i found a solution !

i used this to bypass the error:

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

ErrorHandler:
                If Err.Number = 5991 Or Err.Number = 5941 Then
                    Err.Clear
                    Resume byebye
                End If

```
            For Ro = 4 To ActiveDocument.Tables(4).Rows.Count
            [My ugly code]
#in my case i can use a cell to determinate if it's a my row is merged or not
                If Len(ActiveDocument.Tables(4).Cell(line, 5).Range.Text) > 0 Then
            [My Ugly Code]
```

byebye:

```
            Next Ro
```

Hope my solution can help you...